# How to take a flat JSON file and build a hierarchical menu using PHP

Tags: php, json, menu

I have a database with a list of menu links. Every menu link has an ID in the field 'menu_pages_id'.

In the database there is a field "subPageOf" which says what its parent is. There are also three different kinds of menu links, which is defined in the field "menuType"

I have outputted this list into a flat JSON file, and want to reconstruct the hierarchy.

```
$jsonMenu = json_decode($jsonMenu);
foreach ($jsonMenu as $pageInfo ) {
    $pageUrl = $pageInfo->pageUrl;
    $menuPageName = $pageInfo->pageName;
    $menuType = $pageInfo->menuType;
    $subPageOf = $pageInfo->subPageOf;
    $menu_pages_id = $pageInfo->menu_pages_id;
    
    if( $menuType == 'header' &&  $subPageOf == '0' ){
        $headerMenu .= "<a href='$pageUrl'>$menuPageName</a>"; 
    }
    
    if( $menuType == 'category' &&  $subPageOf == '0'){
        $categoryMenu .= "<li><a href='$pageUrl'>$menuPageName</a></li>";
    }
    
    if( $menuType == 'footer' &&  $subPageOf == '0' ){
        $footerMenu .= "<a href='$pageUrl'>$menuPageName</a>"; 
    } 
}

$categoryMenu = '<ul>'.$categoryMenu.'</ul>';
echo $headerMenu
echo $categoryMenu
echo $footerMenu
```

This will output the first level of course... but how do I nest the sub-pages into the <li> of its parent for the category menus.

I could put another whole foreach loop in the <li> element and run it again filtering for the parent id. But this means I would have to hard code a depth to search for, and it seems like a lot of extra code. I am hoping for a more elegant solution.

Here is an example Json Menu

```
[{"menu_pages_id":"77","menu_id":"1","page_id":"1","listOrder":"0","subPageOf":"0","pageName":"Home","pageUrl":"home","pageType":"system","isProtected":"1","customerGroup":"1001","menuName":"Header Menu","menuType":"header","assignedGroup_id":"1","menuStatus":"Active"},{"menu_pages_id":"78","menu_id":"1","page_id":"14","listOrder":"0","subPageOf":"0","pageName":"About Us","pageUrl":"aboutus","pageType":"content","isProtected":"0","customerGroup":"1001","menuName":"Header Menu","menuType":"header","assignedGroup_id":"1","menuStatus":"Active"},{"menu_pages_id":"80","menu_id":"1","page_id":"6","listOrder":"0","subPageOf":"0","pageName":"Register","pageUrl":"register","pageType":"system","isProtected":"1","customerGroup":"1004","menuName":"Header Menu","menuType":"header","assignedGroup_id":"1","menuStatus":"Active"},{"menu_pages_id":"81","menu_id":"1","page_id":"7","listOrder":"0","subPageOf":"0","pageName":"Your Account","pageUrl":"account","pageType":"system","isProtected":"1","customerGroup":"1003","menuName":"Header Menu","menuType":"header","assignedGroup_id":"1","menuStatus":"Active"},{"menu_pages_id":"82","menu_id":"1","page_id":"9","listOrder":"0","subPageOf":"0","pageName":"Logout","pageUrl":"logout","pageType":"system","isProtected":"1","customerGroup":"1003","menuName":"Header Menu","menuType":"header","assignedGroup_id":"1","menuStatus":"Active"},{"menu_pages_id":"83","menu_id":"2","page_id":"15","listOrder":"0","subPageOf":"0","pageName":"Terms and Conditions","pageUrl":"terms-and-conditions","pageType":"content","isProtected":"0","customerGroup":"1001","menuName":"Footer","menuType":"footer","assignedGroup_id":"1","menuStatus":"Active"},{"menu_pages_id":"84","menu_id":"2","page_id":"44","listOrder":"0","subPageOf":"0","pageName":"Wholesale","pageUrl":"wholesale","pageType":"content","isProtected":"0","customerGroup":"1005, 1007","menuName":"Footer","menuType":"footer","assignedGroup_id":"1","menuStatus":"Active"},{"menu_pages_id":"97","menu_id":"24","page_id":"1","listOrder":"0","subPageOf":"0","pageName":"Home","pageUrl":"home","pageType":"system","isProtected":"1","customerGroup":"1001","menuName":"Test Menu","menuType":"category","assignedGroup_id":"3","menuStatus":"Active"},{"menu_pages_id":"98","menu_id":"24","page_id":"14","listOrder":"0","subPageOf":"0","pageName":"About Us","pageUrl":"aboutus","pageType":"content","isProtected":"0","customerGroup":"1001","menuName":"Test Menu","menuType":"category","assignedGroup_id":"3","menuStatus":"Active"},{"menu_pages_id":"99","menu_id":"24","page_id":"5","listOrder":"0","subPageOf":"97","pageName":"Login","pageUrl":"login","pageType":"system","isProtected":"1","customerGroup":"1004","menuName":"Test Menu","menuType":"category","assignedGroup_id":"3","menuStatus":"Active"},{"menu_pages_id":"100","menu_id":"24","page_id":"3","listOrder":"0","subPageOf":"99","pageName":"Support","pageUrl":"support","pageType":"system","isProtected":"1","customerGroup":"1001","menuName":"Test Menu","menuType":"category","assignedGroup_id":"3","menuStatus":"Active"},{"menu_pages_id":"101","menu_id":"24","page_id":"15","listOrder":"0","subPageOf":"0","pageName":"Terms and Conditions","pageUrl":"terms-and-conditions","pageType":"content","isProtected":"0","customerGroup":"1001","menuName":"Test Menu","menuType":"category","assignedGroup_id":"3","menuStatus":"Active"},{"menu_pages_id":"79","menu_id":"1","page_id":"5","listOrder":"3","subPageOf":"0","pageName":"Login","pageUrl":"login","pageType":"system","isProtected":"1","customerGroup":"1004","menuName":"Header Menu","menuType":"header","assignedGroup_id":"1","menuStatus":"Active"},{"menu_pages_id":"96","menu_id":"1","page_id":"44","listOrder":"8","subPageOf":"0","pageName":"Wholesale","pageUrl":"wholesale","pageType":"content","isProtected":"0","customerGroup":"1005, 1007","menuName":"Header Menu","menuType":"header","assignedGroup_id":"1","menuStatus":"Active"}]
```

Comment: Could you perhaps show you JSON file output. That would help.

Comment: Split into buildDir and buildItem, if item has items -> buildDir, else buildItem, wich will enable the hierarchy via recursion

Comment: @YordanGeorgiev Can you give a code example?

Comment: not in php sorry ... but the principle is the same https://github.com/YordanGeorgiev/qto/blob/c6d65e72fc357bb0aa32e028b15df479fd96cae9/src/perl/qto/templates/controls/list-grid/js/left-menu.js.html.ep#L47

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion should be used i think. Some code based on rough example below shall work:

```
$menus = "your flat menu array";

function getNestedMenu($menus,$subPageOf){
    $nestedMenus = array();
    foreach($menus as $menu){
        if($menu['subPageOf'] = $subPageOf){
            $nestedMenu = $menu;
            $nestedMenu['subPages'] = getNestedMenu($menus,$menu['page_id']);
            $nestedMenus[] = $nestedMenu;
        }
    }
    return $nestedMenus;
}

$myNestedMenus = getNestedMenu($menu,"0");
```

Using above code you can also adapt it to make nested `ul li` based menu `html` code

Comment: For 15 menu items, it is running the loop 432 times. Which seems like too many.  If there was a way to limit it to only run the function again if there was a child... but there is no way to know unless I run the loop. Any ideas?

Comment: I guess to convert a flat array to nested array based on parent, this is one of most straight forward ways. Let us know if you come across any other efficient one.

Comment: As long as its normal, I thought I was doing something wrong. It was also very slow... but it turned out that's because I had an error in the code and PHP was outputting 432 entries in the error log with each run. When I fixed it, it was much faster!

Answer (score 0):

Taking from what Kewlashu said I was able to make it work using the following.

```
$jsonMenu = json_decode($menus);
function makeMenu($jsonMenu,$parentId) {
    $menu .=  "<ul>";
    foreach ($jsonMenu as $pageInfo ) {
        $menuCustomerGroup = $pageInfo->customerGroup;
        $pageUrl = $pageInfo->pageUrl;
        $menuPageName = $pageInfo->pageName;
        $menuType = $pageInfo->menuType;
        $subPageOf = $pageInfo->subPageOf;
        $menu_pages_id = $pageInfo->menu_pages_id;
        if($menuType == 'category' &&  $subPageOf == $parentId){
            $menu .= "<li><a href='$pageUrl'>$menuPageName</a>".makeMenu($jsonMenu,$menu_pages_id)."</li>";
        }   
    }
    $menu .= "</ul>";
    return $menu;    
} 

$menu = makeMenu($jsonMenu,0);
$menu = str_replace("<ul></ul>",'', $menu);
echo $menu;
```

This solution left empty <ul></ul> elements at the bottom of each submenu so I used string replace to remove them before output.

Comment: This answer is not quite right, because it does a LOT of loops, more than are needed.

Comment: Another way to look at it is - this use case is applicable to most of the cases where we need to make dynamic menus and looping a few thousand times (worst case) doesn't reflect badly on page load times. We can also implement a cache mechanism to only create nested structure only when the flat one changes.

Comment: Well as long as it's ok to run that many times! I thought about caching the output, however, the menus might change depending on someone's status... logged in or different permission. I thought about just sending everything, and then using the front end to hide what should not be visible. However I rather not have the potential for the end user to be able to see something they are not supposed to.